# How to open downloaded project?

Tags: defold

I've downloaded *example project* in defold site. it's zip file, how to import it to defold? Do I must create new project and drag all file into it?
Sorry if this is beginner question, thank before.

Comment: No, i ask to import project to defold. not unzip or extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean [these example projects](https://github.com/defold/defold-examples)?

If so, follow these steps:

1. Create a new project in Defold (from dashboard.defold.com) and open it in the editor
2. Right-click
   "game.project" in the Project Explorer and select Show in Finder
   (Mac) or Show in Explorer (PC)
3. Download and unpack the examples
   archive you want
4. Drag the contents of the archive to the location of
   the new project in the Finder/Explorer and replace the files in the
   project The editor will pick up the new files and you are ready to
   go

Alternatively you can **add a project as a library dependency** in your project ('importing' the files for read-only use). If so – add the zip url to the "dependencies" in the project section in "game.project" in Defold. See more about library usage [here](http://www.defold.com/manuals/libraries/).

Answer (score 1):

When you open a project for the first time or download, you need to create a "branch", whch is a copy of the project on your computer. Click "New branch" and name your local working copy (like "my work" or similar).

Also Check Your project compatiboly woth your OS Linux/ Windows and  32 bit or 62 bit.

You can learn basic thing from here .

http://www.defold.com/tutorials/getting-started/

Make sure you are using the latest editor and make sure to clear your browser cache.

Comment: I know for that, i want to explore another tutorial, where downloaded [here] (http://www.defold.com/tutorials/examples/)

Comment: @AepSaepudin Check out Here step by step with video tutorials. http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/Defold-Engine-Tutorial-Series.aspx/